# What is the difference between Bézier splines and Loess curves?

Tags: regression, smoothing, splines, interpolation, loess

I'm a bit naive on this topic, and wanted to understand the difference in the mechanics of Bézier splines and Loess curves as *curve-fitting* methods.

Comment: They're completely different, so different that writing a comparison would be a strange exercise. For one, there is a big difference between interpolation and smoothing.  You've tagged this question well, although I would drop the "curve-fitting" tag and add "interpolation" as a tag, and searching with the tags will show that there are several questions on this forum that should help you understand. The forum doesn't work like Siri.

Comment: "Layman's terms" could mean almost anything. What does it mean here? No equations? No calculus?

Comment: @nick-cox I've edited the question. Thanks for the suggestion. 
**Edit**: Removed the phrase "In layman's terms"; Added the tag "interpolation".

Comment: Thanks, but I think this remains unlikely to be answered as you would wish.